# How do I display an image with CSS in ReactJS?

Tags: css, reactjs

I tried with the following code after importing the image to the src folder. But I can't see the image getting displayed. How to solve this issue?

[image]

My React code is this.

```
import React from 'react'
import burgerLogo from '../../assets/images/burger-logo.png'
import classes from './Logo.module.css'

const logo=(props)=>(
    <div className={classes.Logo} style={{height:props.height}}>
        <image src={burgerLogo} alt="MyBurger"/>
    </div>

);

export default logo;
```

My CSS code is this.

```
.Logo{
    background-color: white;
    padding: 8px;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.Logo img{
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Try instead of using a variable using the path in the image source. I don't think that you need to import the image like that.

Comment: There's no need to import the image like you did

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you change the tag `image` to `img`

```
    <image src={burgerLogo} alt="MyBurger"/>
```

to

```
    <img src={burgerLogo} alt="MyBurger"/>
```

if the import `import burgerLogo from '../../assets/images/burger-logo.png'` is not correct, you will get an error, so that should not be  a problem in your case.

Just want to point that user defined components should start with a capital letter.

> When an element type starts with a lowercase letter, it refers to a
> built-in component like  or  and results in a string 'div'
> or 'span' passed to React.createElement. Types that start with a
> capital letter like  compile to React.createElement(Foo) and
> correspond to a component defined or imported in your JavaScript file.
>
> We recommend naming components with a capital letter. If you do have a
> component that starts with a lowercase letter, assign it to a
> capitalized variable before using it in JSX.

from the [ReactJS docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized)

Coming back to your question

> How do I display an image with CSS in ReactJS?

You can do that using CSS `background-image` property.

Put your image `burger-logo.png` in `public` folder (you can change location if needed eg: inside img or assets folder).

In you CSS use like this

```
.Logo {
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url('./burger-logo.png');
    padding: 8px;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, @kiranvj have you verified with this css approach you are also able to CTRL+P. In my case. I have a logo on React Dialog, when user wants to make print. The logo doesn't show in print preview niether print. Any idea ?

Comment: @khmub try adding `-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;` in the css class. Check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/print-color-adjust) for more details

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your assets folder is inside your public folder do it like this :
`<img src='./assets/images/burger-logo.png' alt="MyBurger"/>`
If it doesn't work, try this
`<img src='./images/burger-logo.png' alt="MyBurger"/>`
It really depends on the path of the image.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your React setup, the `src` for image can vary.

Can you try changing the location of your image file like so:

```js
import burgerLogo from './burger-logo.png'
```

If Webpack is setup to look into a certain folder for `.png` files, it will automatically pick it up from that folder and attach the correct file location behind the scenes.

PS. Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: No console erros. It worked by replacing <image> tag with <img> tag. Thank You